# Deleting elements from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

The following C++ code fills a vector with a number of objects and then removes some of these objects, but it looks like it deletes the wrong ones:

```
vector<Photon>  photons;

photons = source->emitPhotons();    // fills vector with 300 Photon objects

for (int i=0; i<photons.size();  i++) {
    bool useless = false;

    // process photon, set useless to true for some

    // remove useless photons
    if (useless) {
        photons.erase(photons.begin()+i);
    }
}
```

Am I doing this correctly? I'm thinking the line `photons.erase(photons.begin()+i);` might be the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Definietly the wrong way of doing it, you never adjust `i` down as you delete..

Work with iterators, and this problem goes away!

e.g.

```
for(auto it = photons.begin(); it != photons.end();)
{
  if (useless)
    it = photons.erase(it);
  else
    ++it;
}
```

There are other ways using algorithms (such as `remove_if` and `erase` etc.), but above is clearest...

Comment: `warning: 'auto' will change meaning in C++0x; please remove it|`, `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'it' with no type|`

Comment: @Ben, I was being lazy, `auto` is a keyword in c++11 which is very handy, you need to change `auto` to a type, e.g. in this case: `vector<Photon>::iterator`

Comment: +1 It reminds me [this pull request](https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore/pull/5015). People often do this error.

Comment: Thx, short follow-up question though: How can I add an additional photon using this approach, i.e. in the else case?

Comment: @Ben, adding to the vector will invalidate the iterators, and there is no recovery from that (atleast not during a loop - unless you restart from the begining again), an alternative approach may be to put it in a new vector and then once the loop is complete, copy all the items from the new to the `photons` vector.

Comment: Thx, but that's not really feasible as, for the new photons, I need to go through the same for loop again. Would using a list solve that problem?

Comment: @Ben, you can do this with a list, which allows you to insert at the current position - so that may be a better approach if you do this a lot (remove and insert in the middle - a lot).

Answer (score 4):

the elegant way would be:

```
std::vector<Photon> photons = source->emitPhotons();
photons.erase(
      std::remove_if(photons.begin(), photons.end(), isUseless),
      photons.end());
```

and:

```
bool isUseless(const Photon& photon) { /* whatever */ }
```

Comment: Nice. Would you also recommend to use a list instead of the vector? And in case of the list, would it allow me to insert an element into the data structure inside the "for loop"?

Comment: @Ben If you use the [erase-remove-idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) as I showed there won't be a for-loop. There's also no way to modify `photons` inside `isUseless()`.

Comment: @Karl von Moor Again, would you recommend to change your erase-remove-idom to using an std::list instead of the std::vector in my case?

Comment: @Ben I'd recommend std::vector, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1905424/211359)

Answer (score 1):

The proper version will look like:

```
for (vector<Photon>::iterator i=photons.begin(); i!=photons.end(); /*note, how the advance of i is made below*/) {
   bool useless = false;

   // process photon, set useless to true for some

   // remove useless photons
   if (useless) {
     i = photons.erase(i);
   } else {
     ++i;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Erasing elements in the middle of a vector is very inefficient ... the rest of the elements need to be "shifted" back one slot in order to fill-in the "empty" slot in the vector created by the call to `erase`.  If you need to erase elements in the middle of a list-type data-structure without incurring such a penalty, and you don't need O(1) random access time (i.e., you're just trying to store your elements in a list that you'll copy or use somewhere else later, and you always iterate through the list rather than randomly accessing it), you should look into `std::list` which uses an underlying linked-list for its implementation, giving it O(1) complexity for modifications to the list like insert/delete.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with stl::list in this case. Quoting the STL docs:

> Lists have the important property that insertion and splicing do not invalidate iterators to list elements, **and that even removal invalidates only the iterators that point to the elements that are removed.**

So this would go along the lines of:

```
std::list<Photon> photons;
photons = source->emitPhotons();
std::list<Photon>::iterator i;
for(i=photons.begin();i!=photons.end();++i)
{
    bool useless=false;
    if(useless)
        photons.erase(i);
}
```

Comment: That crashes my program. I've  modified it to take `i++` out of the for loop and put it in the else case instead. And adding `it =` in front of the delete. This works, however it actually feels like it takes a lot longer than the vector approach I used earlier!?