# Is there a standard container that allows inserting elements without invalidating iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

In C++, is there a data structure that allows me to add elements to it within the following for-loop?

(I used a `list` as an example because that's what I've tried so far.)

```
list<Elem> elems;
// fill elems with some Elems;

for(list<Elem>::iterator it=elems.begin(); it!=elems.end();) {

    // ...

    if(condition)
        it = elems.erase(it);
    else {
        Elem elem;
        it = elems.push_back(elem);
    }
}
```

PS: This is a follow-up question to [Deleting elements from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228705/deleting-elements-from-a-vector)

Comment: Don't do this. Build a new container and then replace the original with it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, if you care to elaborate on that, I think it would make a good answer.  That's an approach none of the existing answers cover yet.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6438087/5987) gives a good summary of the behavior of all the standard containers.

The containers that won't invalidate iterators on an insertion or erase are `list`, `set`, `multiset`, `map`, and `multimap`. Of course this excludes the iterator being erased.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `list` allows you to do this.. as I said in my comment in the other answer...

Comment: So how do I do it? Because `it = elems.push_back(elem);` can't work (return value is void).

Comment: if you want to add it to the end, simply call `push_back()`, if you want to insert at the current position, call `insert(it, value);` - this will return you an iterator you can continue with...

Comment: This means that if I do `it = elems.insert(elem)`, I should be fine?

Comment: @Ben, the insert function requires the iterator as the current position to insert at..

Answer (score 1):

Writing this per request.

> PS: This is a follow-up question to Deleting elements from a vector

This is a troubling pattern in your line of questioning.

Seriously, modifying containers while you're iterating over them is bad juju. It is difficult to get right. It often doesn't save you much in terms of performance. It's rarely (except in limited cases where there's a standard library algorithm exactly suited to your needs) easier to express. It can be very costly in performance if you do it wrong. It can be very costly in terms of program correctness if you do it wrong, which is much more important than anything else.

It gets exponentially worse if threading is involved. Java has a dedicated exception type specifically for certain things that can go wrong when you attempt this. In C++ you aren't so lucky; the analogous problem might not be detectable.

Just write code that produces the final result, then replace the original container. The only thing that can really slow this down is "instances are expensive to copy", in which case you should already be using a layer of indirection to handle the problem (assuming it really matters) anyway.

```
list<Elem> original;
// fill elems with some Elems;
list<Elem> modified;
for (
    list<Elem>::iterator it = original.begin(), end = original.end();
    it != end; ++it
) {
    if (something()) {
        modified.push_back(*it);
    } else if (something_else()) {
        modified.push_back(Elem()); // for example
    }
    // else, 'erase' the element by just not putting anything into 'modified'
    // Or we could do whatever other combination of things,
    // maybe insert more than one
}
std::swap(original, modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [several containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9230943/46821) that support insertion without invalidating iterators.  In your code, you have the removal case right, but I believe you're over-thinking the insert case.  Try this:

```
else {
    Elem elem;
    elems.push_back(elems);
    ++it;
}
```

You're using a `list` in the given example, so you know the `push_back` call won't invalidate `it`.  Thus, you can simply increment it to get to the next element.  You only have to be careful when [removing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/596162/46821) because you can't increment an iterator that points to a place that no longer exists.