# If linked lists have many functional advantages over arrays, what advantages do arrays have over linked lists?

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

Linked lists advantages I see are infinite dynamic space and auto updating capability between lists. Arrays lack the many useful functions of linked lists. So why would you use arrays in some cases instead of linked lists?

Comment: Linked lists do not have good random access.

Comment: Linked lists have some advantages, but memory contiguity is a big deal.

Comment: You can access any element of an array in O(1).

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209224/vector-vs-list-in-stl) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905417/array-vs-vector-vs-list)

Comment: *I don't know of a single one!* -- Have you done proper research?

Comment: This [benchmark](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html) report may be of interest to you.

Comment: Aeroplanes can fly long distances, but potatoes fly short distances at best, and land poorly. So why not make vodka from aeroplanes? Answer: because these are different uses. Sometimes random access, or cache-friendliness, are more important than your "many useful functions". Sometimes they're not. You choose a container according to your requirements, every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no free lunch.

In general, if a data structure is more powerful than another, you will have to pay for that additional power somehow. Sometimes you will not be willing to pay that price.

As for lists, you are correct, in terms of functionality, they are way better than arrays:

- You can efficiently insert and delete elements anywhere in the list without having to copy existing elements around
- Lists can grow indefinitely. If you want a growing array, you basically have to copy all existing elements to the bigger array and then throw away the old one.
- You can efficiently [move elements from one list to another](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) without copying.

Arrays can do none of that!

But because arrays don't have to support these features, they also don't have to pay for the additional complexities that list implementations introduce:

- A list has to allocate each of its elements separately. This means more complex lifetime management for the implementation and a lot of calls to `new` and `delete`. You will not notice this in small programs, but those calls are very slow, and what is worse, they get slower the more you use them.
- Because the elements are allocated independently, they might end up scattered all over memory. This is bad for caching, because caches work best if all the data is close together in memory. On modern desktop machines this can have a huge impact on performance, as accessing memory is significantly slower than accessing the cache. It is in fact so big, that more often than not, the additional work that you have to do with arrays in terms of copying elements around is still cheaper than having to deal with the bad caching behavior of lists.
- Arrays allow for random access. That means I can always directly locate any element of the array from its index. With lists, I need to traverse the list, so if my element is further back in the list, it will take me longer to reach it. Also, bigger lists take longer to traverse than smaller ones. If I frequently use algorithms that need to perform a series of random accesses quickly, using arrays can be a big performance win. Binary search is an obvious example.

So, as you can see, there is a trade-off. The added flexibility is great, but it comes at a cost that might bite you depending on what you want to do with the data structure. The same is true for all data structures by the way. Trees for example solve the slow lookup problem of lists to some extent, but they have other drawbacks compared to lists and arrays. It is important that you as a programmer familiarize yourself with the different strengths and weaknesses of the different data structures, so that you can chose the right one for each problem.

Comment: Awesome answer! I totally get the trade off concept and why it defines which one you would use depending on what you want them to hold and what you want to do with your code!

Answer (score 4):

Arrays have random access with O(1) speed.  Arrays can determine length at compile time.  Data in arrays is contiguous, which means that it is extremely CPU-memory-cache friendly.  Arrays don't have per-element effort spent on overhead, like next/previous pointers, so are more compact.

Linked lists are a node based data structures.  Without extreme effort, they are very cache unfriendly.  They are bulky -- a list of bytes could have 1600%+ container overhead, more than 17x the size of an equivalent array.

`std::vector` is a dynamic array.  In practice, with the cost of actually finding the element to work with, `std::vector` beats the pants off of `std::list` in almost every situation you can profile.  There are a few exceptions, mainly involving data stability in memory and iterator persistance.

Comment: I can see now how linked lists are at a distinct disadvantage with arrays. If arrays accomplish what you need, there's no reason to use linked lists as it would just take longer to compile. In today's world, application speed is extremely important to the consumer.

Comment: @GulpDragondawn It is extremely rare that a `std::list` is a better idea than a `std::vector`.  There are cases, but they are few and far between.  They mainly involve the iterator, reference and pointer stability of `std::list` that `std::vector` lacks.  And generic pointer lists (not `std::list`s) can have fast splicing.